# Extract day number from day string

Tags: mysql, converters, weekday

Is it possible to extract an integer value from day names, i.e. "Mon", Tue", "Wed" with an SQL statement?

For example:

```
 Mon = 1
 Tue = 2
 Wed = 3
```

Comment: Do you only need it to work for the English language?

Answer (score 9):

Try FIELD:

```
SELECT FIELD('Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
    -> 1
SELECT FIELD('Thu', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
    -> 4
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Answer (score 5):

If you simply have a non-datetime field with just Mon, Tue, Wed, etc, you can use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) functions to come up with something like this:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201011 ', yourField), '%X%V %W')) + 1 AS WeekIndex;
```

Test Case:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201011 ', 'Mon'), '%X%V %W')) + 1 AS WeekIndex;
+-----------+
| WeekIndex |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+

SELECT WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201011 ', 'Tue'), '%X%V %W')) + 1 AS WeekIndex;
+-----------+
| WeekIndex |
+-----------+
|         2 |
+-----------+

SELECT WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201011 ', 'Wed'), '%X%V %W')) + 1 AS WeekIndex;
+-----------+
| WeekIndex |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+

SELECT WEEKDAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('201011 ', 'Thu'), '%X%V %W')) + 1 AS WeekIndex;
+-----------+
| WeekIndex |
+-----------+
|         4 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If your field is a date field, just use

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my.field, "%w");
```

More Info on MySQLs DATE_FORMAT can be optained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Answer (score 1):

```
DAYOFWEEK(date);
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-date-time-functions.htm#function_dayofweek